# Move files to the same folder with different extension

Tags: linux

I want to change files from specific extension to another. (for example '.txt' to '.md'). I am able to extract the file basename. However, I fail to get the file path and also to move it to the same folder. My current progress is below.

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs -I '{}' -L1 -p sh -c 'basename "$@" .md' "$0"
```

I thank you for any help.

Best regards,
Bruno Peixoto

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

```
for f in *.txt; do 
    mv -- "$f" "${f%.txt}.md"
done
```

`--` here [marks the end of the option list](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash). This avoids issues with filenames starting with hyphens.

Comment: I would like to use file from the "find" statement.

Comment: It is a good solution:

for f in $(find . -type f -name "*.txt"); do mv -- "$f" "${f%.txt}.md"; done

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto [No](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). The answer is exactly the solution to this kind of flawed code.

Comment: The evoked reasons of flaw do not occur in my case.

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto The answer is not solely for you. The answer is for you *and* for future users with similar problems. Besides, how could we know in advance? Writing robust code is a virtue.

Comment: Nobody can know everything in advance.